# Read array sections in namelist

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran-namelist

Consider a namelist containing two-dimensional arrays.
For example, the following program reads from a file "input.dat".

```fortran
program test
    use :: iso_fortran_env

    implicit none

    integer :: ierr, unit, i
    real(kind=kind(0.0d0)), allocatable :: p(:, :)

    namelist /VAR_p/ p

    allocate(p(2,2))
    open(newunit=unit, file='input.dat', status='old', iostat=ierr)
    read(unit, nml=VAR_p, iostat=ierr)
    close(unit)

    do i = 1, size(p, 1)
        write(output_unit, '(F4.2," ",F4.2)') p(i,1), p(i,2)
    end do
end program test
```

One can provide the array p in "input.dat" as

```fortran
! input.dat
&VAR_p
p(1,1) = 1.2
p(1,2) = 3.2
p(2,1) = 1.0
p(2,2) = 0.0
/
```

With this input the program runs fine. Nevertheless, I would rather prefer to provide the array p line-by-line. Something like

```fortran
! input.dat
&VAR_p
p(1,:) = (1.2, 3.2)
p(2,:) = (1.30, 0.0)
/
```

Is there a syntax to achive that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed a syntax to specify an array section in a namelist record.  It's close to the requested form, but not quite.

In a namelist record, the item `(1.30, 0.0)` specifies a complex value not an array constructor (which means the generalization to `(1.3, 0.0, 1.2)` isn't a valid value).  Instead you simply want to specify a list of values: `1.3, 0.0`:

```
&VAR_p
p(1,:) = 1.2, 3.2
p(2,:) = 1.30, 0.0
/
```

There are some restrictions of note:

- the left-hand side designator may be an array section, but it may not be a vector subscript;
- the number of values on the right-hand side may not be greater than the number of array elements on the left-hand side.

In this second case, if there are fewer values on the right-hand side than elements on the left, then it's as though the right-hand side were padded with null values.